# I am having a doubt in graphs of $4πr^2|\psi|^2$ vs $r$ and $4πr^2|R(r)|^2$ vs $r$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

To show radial probability, in some sources they used the graph $4πr^2|\psi|^2$ vs $r$

In some other sources, they used the graph $4πr^2|R(r)|^2$ vs $r$

However, $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$, where $R(r)$ is the radial function, and $Y(\theta, \phi)$ is the angular function

But the same graph is drawn for both of these equations. So does $Y(\theta,\phi)$ have no significance in graph? If not, what is the explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For Hydrogen atom, the wave function look like
$$\psi(r,\theta ,\phi)=R_{El}(r)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$

---

When one is interested in only radial distribution, that is How the probability changes with radial distance.
$$|\psi(r)|^2=\int |\psi(r,\theta,\phi)|^2d\Omega=\int|R_{El}(r)|^2|Y_l^m(r,\theta)|^2d\Omega=|R_{El}(r)|^2\int Y_l^m(r,\theta)|^2d\Omega \propto|R_{El}(r)|^2$$
So It doesn't matter.

Comment: Clear, thank you So Much!!!